# slabtop command doesn't work

Tags: centos, cache, kernel, memory-usage

I've inherited Sys Admin duties on webserver and I'm a bit of out my element, but learning as I go. My newest issue is all the of the ram has been gobbled up and I'm not sure where it has gone.

`free -m` gives me

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          4096       4077         18          0          0        119
-/+ buffers/cache:       3957        138
Swap:         1024        127        896
```

Through research, I've read I should be looking at kernel caching, however when I run `slabtop` I get this error: `fopen /proc/slabinfo: No such file or directory`

How do I repair slabtop so I can determine what is going on?

```
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
2.6.32-042stab104.1
```

Comment: It looks like the server is properly releasing the memory as needed so this is less urgent that previously thought. Still, I'd like to know how to fix slabtop. This is relatively fresh CentOS install, so I'm not sure why it doesn't function.

Comment: Which procps and kernel do you have?

Comment: I listed the kernel in the original question I thought? `cat /proc/version` gives me `Linux version 2.6.32-042stab104.1 (root@kbuild-rh6-x64) (gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Jan 29 12:58:41 MSK 2015`.

I am not sure how to get `procps` version?

Comment: yum info procps

Comment: x86_64 Version 3.2.8 Release 25.el6